# Some issue about setup slcli Softlayer api

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

setup with following commands

```
$ pip install softlayer
$ curl -sL https://ibm.biz/idt-installer | bash
$ ibmcloud plugin install auto-scaling
```

when I using slcli command, it report error. Is it still missing something?

```
$ slcli vs list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SSO/hills/.local/bin/slcli", line 7, in <module>
    from SoftLayer.CLI.core import main
  File "/home/SSO/hills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from SoftLayer.API import *  # NOQA
  File "/home/SSO/hills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 15, in <module>
    from SoftLayer import transports
  File "/home/SSO/hills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 248
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString) from ex
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: As of version 5.8.0 SoftLayer-Python will no longer support python2.7, I recommend updating your python. please review this link https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python#python-27-support

Comment: ```
response = client.request(‘POST’, url, data=payload, headers=transport_headers, timeout=timeout,
               verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxy, auth=auth)
xml = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
ElementTree.dump(xml)
==========================
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Account): No valid authentication headers found.
```
Do you have idea of this message.

Comment: could you review this link https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/authenticating-softlayer-api/